# Is there a better way to avoid subqueries in this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have the following schema that i need to query. `MyDomainObject` is an object that has a bunch of values that can be associated with it, and one or more values can be changed in the same transaction, pointing at a single `ChangeRecord`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyDomainObject (
 domain_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
 domain_name text UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ChangeRecord (
  change_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  change_when timestamptz,
  change_source text NOT NULL,
  change_comment text
);

CREATE TABLE StringColumn (
  domain_id integer REFERENCES MyDomainObject,
  change_id integer REFERENCES ChangeRecord,
  column_name text NOT NULL, 
  str_value text NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (domain_id, change_id, column_name)
);

CREATE TABLE IntegerColumn (
  domain_id integer REFERENCES MyDomainObject,
  change_id integer REFERENCES ChangeRecord,
  column_name text NOT NULL, 
  int_value text NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (domain_id, change_id, column_name)
);
```

I need to query the latest value/timetamp/source tuple of a set of columns and the solution i arrived at uses subqueries.

```sql
SELECT
  mdo.domain_id, mdo.domain_name,
  ( SELECT (sc.str_value, cr.change_when, cr.change_source)
    FROM StringColumn sc JOIN ChangeRecord cr USING (change_id)
    WHERE column_name = 'some_field' and mdo.domain_id = sc.domain_id
    ORDER BY cr.change_when DESC LIMIT 1 
  ) AS some_field,
  ( SELECT (ic.int_value, cr.change_when, cr.change_source)
    FROM IntegerColumn ic JOIN ChangeRecord cr USING (change_id)
    WHERE column_name = 'another_field' and mdo.domain_id= ic.domain_id
    ORDER BY cr.change_when DESC LIMIT 1 
  ) AS another_field,
  ( SELECT (ic.int_value, cr.change_when, cr.change_source)
    FROM IntegerColumn ic JOIN ChangeRecord cr USING (change_id)
    WHERE column_name = 'yet_another_field' and mdo.domain_id= ic.domain_id
    ORDER BY cr.change_when DESC LIMIT 1 
  ) AS yet_another_field
FROM MyDomainObject mdo
```

I'm worried that once my dataset grows large, this query will slow right down due to running `MxN` queries where `M` is the number of `MyDomainObject` rows, and `N` is the number of fields i need to retrieve. Is there any way to use joins to make this faster?

Comment: just use a join?

Comment: No, unfortunately you picked [the worst conceivable data model](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/entity-attribute-value-eav-design-in-postgresql-dont-do-it/), and there is not much you can do to get good performance.

Comment: @theemee I tried, but could not find the magic incarnation to get a join working right.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I agree with a lot of the points that article makes, but I really do need to keep track of when fields change and why. That said, the article has convinced me to de-normalize a little and store the latest value of each column on the domain object, and use the change tracking tables just for querying history.